# How can i reload or restart function after every 5 minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement an auto save functionality with using a jQuery.
I done it and it's working fine but the issues i want it auto reload or auto restart after 5 minutes or whatever time we put in script.
anyone please help me sort it out.

Whiteboard will auto save in 4 minutes and 59 seconds.

```
jQuery('.clock').each(function () {
            var clock = jQuery(this);
            setInterval(function () {
                var m = jQuery('.min', clock),
                    s = jQuery('.sec', clock);

                if (m.length == 0 && parseInt(s.html()) <= 0){
                    clock.html('Timer Complete.');
                   jQuery('#btnSave').trigger('click');
                }
                if (parseInt(s.html()) <= 0) {
                    m.html(parseInt(m.html() - 1));
                    s.html(60);
                }
                if (parseInt(m.html()) <= 0)
                    clock.html('Whiteboard will auto save in <span class="sec">59</span> seconds.');
              s.html(parseInt(s.html() -1));
            }, 1000);

        });
```

Comment: setInterval(function(){
    console.log("hello");
}, (4 * 60 * 1000) + (59 * 1000));

Comment: If you could make a js fiddle out of your code which is `working fine` according to you.

Comment: What is it doing now? How do you know it is not working?

Comment: I am going to try your code on http://jsfiddle.net/ and fix it and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after counting down is complete 'Timer Complete.', you should reset your .min and .sec to the chosen time

```
if (m.length == 0 && parseInt(s.html()) <= 0){
    // clock.html('Timer Complete.');
    jQuery('#btnSave').trigger('click');
    m.html('4');
    s.html('59');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the combination of setInterval and a function checking your time status. like this :

```
    setInterval(checkAutoSave(),10000); // recall function every 10 seconds

    var timeVal;
    function checkAutosave() {
      timeVal += 10;
      if (timeVal === 300) { // 300 seconds
          autoSave();
          timeVal = 0;
      }
}
```